# how to combine fasta files?

Tags: sequence, cat, fasta

My question is regarding concatenating two gene sequences into a combined file. Here are four of example file names

```
IMB211_trasncripts.renamed-20175.fa
IMB211_trasncripts.renamed-20176.fa
R500_trasncripts.renamed-20175.fa
R500_trasncripts.renamed-20176.fa
```

Basically i want to concatenate `IMB211_trasncripts.renamed-20175.fa` with `R500_trasncripts.renamed-20175.fa` and `IMB211_trasncripts.renamed-20176.fa` with `R500_trasncripts.renamed-20176.fa`. I know this is simple using `cat` command.

```
cat MB211_trasncripts.renamed-20175.fa R500_trasncripts.renamed-20175.fa > test_comb-20175.fa
```

However i have around 40 thousand genes like these (each for IMB211 and R500) and so i am wondering is there a easy way around to concatenate these files into one file specific for each gene id?

Thanks

Comment: You any good with scripting? Seems like there's a reasonably simple solution involving bash; use  [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and `uniq` to generate the list of suffixes and prefixes, then loop over both to create the new sequences.

Comment: You could also pass the files *.fa to cat to concatenate in a script (I am not sure how to do it in a command line)